# Como inverter palavras e contar o total de caracteres

Tags: php

Como eu faço via php/html, com que por exemplo, eu tenha um `input` pro usuário digitar qualquer coisa, e na hora que ele clicar no botão "OK", eu retorne a palavra que ele digitou de forma invertida, e a quantidade de caracteres da palavra que por ele foi digitado?

Eu sei que eu vou ter que usar os métodos `strlen()` e `strrev()`, mas não tô sabendo fazer. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Grato

Comment: Julio, bem vindo ao so. Sua pergunta não estava dentro dos padrões do site, por isso foi editada. Caso não concorde, edite-a, porem, melhorando-a. Visite [Como criar uma boa pergunta](/help/how-to-ask) para saber como fazer uma boa pergunta.

Comment: Não vai usar nenhuma dessas funções xD por incrivel.

Answer (score 7):

Caso o encode (ISO-8859-1) esteja configurado corretamente as funções `strlen()` e `strrev()` funcionam como o esperado, se estiver usando UTF-8 prefira a abordagem abaixo.

`stlen()` Não conta o número de caracteres mas o de byte, um exemplo prático é entrada `ação` retorna 6(bytes) e não 4(caracteres), para caracteres com enconde multibite use `mb_strlen()`.

`strrev()` sofre do mesmo problema, não trata caracteres multibyte logo não faz a inversão corretamente, nesse caso use regex para resolver o trabalho.

Exemplo com `strlen()` & `strrev()`

```
$str = 'AÇÃO';
printf("%s - %s caracteres - invertido: %s", $str, strlen($str), strrev($str));
```

Sáida:

```
AÇÃO - 6 caracteres - invertido: O�Ç�A
```

Exemplo com regex & `mb_strlen()`

```
function mb_strrev($str){
    preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
    return implode('', array_reverse($ar[0]));
}

$str = 'AÇÃO';
printf("%s - %s caracteres - invertido: %s", $str, strlen($str), strrev($str));
```

Sáida:

```
AÇÃO - 4 caracteres - invertido: OÃÇA
```

Comment: Bacana a abortagem sobre os charsets! Detalhe interessante!

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro algo assim:

```
 $input = $_GET['nome_do_campo'];
 $invertido = strrev($input);
 $tamanho = strlen($input);

echo "String invertida: <em>{$invertido}</em>. O tamanho é de <strong>{$tamanho}</strong> caracteres";
```

Answer (score 5):

Simples

```
<?php

    $string = (isset($_POST['input1'])) ? trim($_POST['input1']) : null;

    $stringInvertida = strrev($string);
    $qntCaracteres = strlen($string);

    echo "Seu texto invertido é: {$stringInvertida} e contem {$qntCaracteres} caractere(s).";
```

No seu formulário HTML, defina o `name do input` que irá receber a string como `input1`

Comment: Obrigado fera!!

Comment: @JúlioCésar, se não for complicado pra você, opte pela resposta do rray, é mais completa e eficaz.

Comment: Então brother, por algum motivo, só tá me respondendo 0

Comment: Segue os códigos

Comment: @JúlioCésar, verifique nas propriedade do seu form se tem method="post" e se o name do input está correto.

Answer (score 1):

Uma versão com suporte a caracteres multibyte:

```
$str = '日本語'; // teste essa palavra alienígena
$str = 'Ação'; // ou será que essa palavra é alienígena?

echo 'quantidade de letras: '.mb_strlen($str);
echo PHP_EOL.'<br />inverso: '.join('', array_reverse(preg_split('~~u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
```

A função nativa `strrev()` não é "multibyte safe", por isso, a implementação usando `join()`, `array_reverse()` e `preg_split()`.

A função `mb_strlen()` é específica para caracteres multibyte e retorna a quantidade de caracteres. Não confunda com quantidade de bytes.

Caso queira saber a quantidade de bytes, utilize `strlen()`.

Veja a diferença

```
$str = 'Ação';
echo strlen($str).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo mb_strlen($str).PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Bom exemplo +1.